# LINQ to Entities DeleteAllOnSubmit throws Unknown Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I'm re-writing an app that used to use LINQ to SQL DeleteAllOnSubmit and am now using LINQ to Entities in an MVC5 application.  MSDN showed the way to structure my L2E code.  However, I receive Unknown Method for the following snippet:

```
IEnumerable<QuoteItem> quoteItemsToDelete = (from qi in QuoteItem
where qi.QuoteID = q.QuoteID
select qi).ToList();
QuoteItem.DeleteAllOnSubmit(quoteItemsToDelete);
SubmitChanges();
```

The L2S snippet I'm trying to replace is as follows:

```
    HttpContext.Current.GetDataContext().QuoteItems.
    DeleteAllOnSubmit<QuoteItem>(q.QuoteItems);
```

Based on comments received, I modified the code as follows:

```
using (var ctx = new FreightEntities())
        {
            var quoteitemtoDelete = ctx.QuoteItems.Remove();
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

However, this causes `Unknown Method Remove() of System.Data.Entity.DbSet`

How should I modify my L2E code to accomplish the same purpose as the L2S syntax?

Comment: are you looking for `Remove()`?

Comment: Is that the equivalent to the L2S snippet I referenced?

Comment: @SidC Yes. Use Remove(). There is no DeleteAllOnSubmit() in L2E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something on following lines should work for you:

```
    public void DeleteAllOnSubmit<T>(IEnumerable<T> items) where T : class
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Set<T>().Attach(item);
            Set<T>().Remove(item);
        }

        SaveChanges();
    }
```

Basically you will have to loop through each item and call Remove passing single item at a time.

To know more about Remove method refer [DbSet.Remove()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.remove(v=vs.113).aspx)

With EF Code First all you need to delete an entity is to attach it and set its state to Deleted. This is demonstrated [Delete Entity using DBContext](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/delete-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx)

Comment: It's my understanding that DeleteAllOnSubmit is not available in LINQ to Entities?

Comment: Its not, you can define a method in your context class.

Comment: @SidC - Does that make sense? I dont know what you have got in FreightEntities, basically such CRUD methods goes in DbContext implementation class. I rename my RemoveAll() to DeleteAllOnSubmit(). Let me know if you need any explanation around it.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit further?  Thanks!

Comment: @SidC - I updated my answer with more information around Remove method plus another way to delete entities. If you have specific question please share.